# Neo4j Indexing methodology

Tags: mysql, indexing, neo4j, compare

I am new to Neo4j and trying to understand it's schema. It mentions that it now uses Schema indexing with its recent versions and it used to have Manual Indexing/Auto indexing in previous versions.

However, it doesn't talk about which indexing method it internally uses and how the indexes are maintained. For example, MySql uses B+tree indexing internally and we are able to actually estimate how much value it adds to the existing database upon creating an index. I know MySql and Neo4j are different in how they store and do the data retrieval/visualization but just using it as a reference here.

In case of Neo4j, I couldn't find a discussion on these things except mentioning that it has 3 types of indexes.

Does any one has any idea on it?

### Thanks in advance.

Shiva

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're after. Neo4j uses Lucene for indexing. Check [here](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/) and [here](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2014/10/deep-dive-on-fulltext-indexing-with-neo4j/).

Comment: Thanks for your references @user2338089. Actually, I am looking for the indexing scheme that is used internally and how does neo4j use indexing internally to manage nodes?